# Question closed as duplicate, but no link given?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I was looking for an answer to another question, when I came across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13759278) in which had been closed as a duplicate, but there didn’t seem to be a link to said dupe.

My understanding was that the duplicated question would have been linked.

This may have been a misunderstanding on my part, but if possible is the something that could be looked into / explained why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A long time ago, the duplicate links got edited into the post by the Community user, which also meant they could be edited *out* of the post without actually reopening the question.

I've rolled back the edit that removed the duplicate link from the question.