# Questions Marked Duplicate Should (Must) Have Link to Original

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, hyperlinks

I run across questions marked duplicate fairly often. Unfortunately, the actual duplicate question notice does not contain a link to the question allegedly duplicated. Occasionally, some kind soul includes a link in a comment, or reply, but this is the exception.

IMHO, the notification that a question is duplicate should (as in must) contain a link to the question supposedly duplicated. I assume (yes, yes, I know), that the moderators have actually viewed the allegedly duplicated question to know that the newer post is really a duplicate. If that's true, then they have the link, and there's no reason not to include it.

Comment: doesn't it already do this? (way at the top)

Comment: Links or it didn't happen.

Comment: You mean which? The comments that say "possible duplicate of" with a link? Or the duplicate banner, which links into the dupe as well? I'm confused about what you say.... do you mean FLAGGED as a dupe?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280655

Comment: Orrrrr that @davidism I think it would've been nice to see which question OP is mentioning before posting my answer n_n'

Answer (score 4):

The feature you request already exists.

[image]

When you see the *"Possible duplicate of..."* comment is cause the question has been flagged or voted to close as a dupe, but it hasn't been marked as a dupe yet.

Although as @animuson mentions in his [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280656/5067286), referenced by a comment thanks to @davidism. You might've encountered one of these old questions where the dupe link had to be edited into the question.