# Duplicate without a link

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Here is a [weird question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5865937/728795), to me anyway. Weird because it is clearly closed as a duplicate, but it does not have a link to the thread it was closed in favor of.

There is the edit history though, and from there it looks like the dupe link was added as a part of a question post, and then edited out by the OP.

1. Just curious, what's going on there with these edits?
2. What should be done with this one now? Should it be opened (comments seem to suggest it wasn't a dupe after all, and it does get a lot of traffic)? Or perhaps closed as a dupe of something else?

Comment: I'm puzzled.. The question is poor and has a typo: using `"` broke the string even SO higlight saw it. The correct answer is indead in the duplicate link: "You won't be able to render HTML tags". It's a strick equivalent to "content doesn't support HTML".

Comment: Sorta-cross-meta-duplicate: [Should this question closed as duplicate without a link to the duplicate be reopened?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/165865) (a post from before the change to a fixed banner).

Comment: Part of this question is a duplicate of [Question Closed as duplicate, but no link given?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280655/4642212).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Previously, when a question was closed as a duplicate, the *Possible duplicate* notification was edited into the question by the community user. This allowed everyone to add new duplicates or alter this information.

This question was marked as a duplicate while that system was still active. In the new system, only gold badge users can edit the duplicate information, and the only way to fully remove it is by re-opening the question.

Unfortunately, the OP of that question unilaterally decided his question wasn't a duplicate and edited that notification out without actually getting the question re-opened. I've edited it back in, if the behavior continues we can ask a mod to re-open the question and close it again (so it falls into the new system, and OP can no longer edit the notification out).

Comment: I've  reopened and re-duped the post to move the banner out of the post. The OP won't be able to edit it out anymore.