# Why is the link to the duplicate missing?

Tags: support

The question [Splitting a C++ std::string using tokens, e.g. ";"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167625/splitting-a-c-stdstring-using-tokens-e-g) has been closed as a duplicate of another question. But the link to the duplicate is missing.

Why is that so?

How would one go about fixing it?

PS. [Question Closed as duplicate, but no link given?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280655/question-closed-as-duplicate-but-no-link-given) is a similar post but corresponds to a different question on SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Someone edited it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5167625/4)  I've rolled that back.

For those not in the know, it used to be the case that "Possible Duplicate" would appear in the text of the question itself as opposed to external to it, so it was vulnerable to these kinds of revisions.