# Duplicate with no targets

Tags: support, bug, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11271263/13860) is closed as a duplicate, with no dupe target.

[image]

I've seen a few similar posts here on meta, which appear to have been fixed. Does this require manual mod intervention to fix?

Is meta the right place to report such things, or should such problems be raised in a flag?

Answer (score 7):

In [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11271263/revisions) we can see that the OP disagreed with the duplicate decision and removed the banner that the [Community ♦ User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) automatically added on the start of the question - but wasn't able to reopen the question to fix the underlying issue.

I've since re-added the banner.

<s>It should be possible (and would be preferable) for a user holding a gold badge in [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) (or a diamond moderator) to edit the list of duplicates for the question and roll back my 'fix'.</s>

On 2021-02-21 the OP removed the banner that I added - then on 2022-01-07 the post was reopened and closed normally as a duplicate (with the normal banner). The post is currently in the reopen queue.

---

Related:

- [Question closed as duplicate, but no link given?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280655/1364007) - the banner was re-added in this case: note that this was before [*New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/284827) so things were done with the banner added to the start of duplicate questions back then.
- [This question already has answers where?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391505/1364007) - the question was reopened for four seconds while a diamond moderator (also a gold-badge holder in a relevant tag) re-closed it to point to the duplicate target.

  The [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391506/1364007) to the (Meta) question by [Cody Gray ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) says:

  > This [has been noted before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337282), but there's no good way of automatically correcting these—mass editing of a bunch of questions always makes me nervous, and, as I mentioned above, that "possible duplicate of" banner may not have survived intact over the years. Instead, we just correct them manually by re-opening and closing as a duplicate of the same post. Any gold badge holder can do this with a single vote and a minimum of fuss, as can a diamond moderator.

  ...

  > If you come across additional anomalous questions, please raise a moderator flag or ping a gold badge holder in chat (if you're a regular anywhere where they hang out).

Comment: I guess that's better than nothing, but it's still not in the banner proper.

Comment: Yeah - I'm looking for a related question/bug report on Meta about the change to the proper banners.

Comment: I noticed that the OP of that question had removed the banner you had restored. I would actually tend to agree that it is not a duplicate, as he had actually explained when removing it. Anyway, I have flagged that post for moderator attention to get it properly fixed – I don’t want to start an edit war, and a reopen vote would leave the post broken if reviewers don’t agree.

Comment: @DidierL - good spot. I've edited the post. Your flag seems to have resulted in the question being closed - it's in the reopen queue now.

Comment: Yep, I guess the mod didn’t want to take a unilateral decision to reopen it. I have also edited the link the OP put in his edit to align it with the duplicate’s new title, and voted to reopen.